# _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError - how to deal with?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Using python's `MySQLDB` to connect to a `MariaDB` database;
I am runnging a benign loop of `SELECT`s that for some unknown reason breaks due to

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now)
```

What I do not understand is how to properly handle catching the exception:
I can catch the exception, but then in the next loop the error state persists in the database and is only cleared when I stop the script and re-initialize my `MySQLDB` `cursor` object.

How can I properly identify what the cause is? Running the queries out of the terminal does not break. How can I reset the `cursor` object within my exception handling?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix it myself. 
Turns out I had one extra " in one of the queries that broke the cursor somehow...